# Does increasing the replication factor improve read latency?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

If we increase the replication factor, does it improve read latency in case of Cassandra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your read consistency level.  If you're reading at `*_ONE`, it won't make a difference.  If you're reading at `*_QUORUM`, it will likely *increase* latency (more replicas to read and reconcile).

In short, increasing the RF will not improve (lower) read latency.  In fact, the best case scenario is that it doesn't affect it at all.

On the other hand, if your cluster is serving tens of thousands of reads per second, adding nodes (with the same RF) should improve read latency.  This of course is assuming that your current cluster nodes are overwhelmed during high throughput scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, you mentioned that the addition of nodes may improve read latency. I understand this will be because the data will then be distributed across more nodes. A read can then in parallel get the data from multiple nodes. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @RajibDeb Yes, that's correct.